# How do I clearing an index property in a valueObject?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have used the index of a value object to map to a screen object so that new items added index as -1, -2, -3, -4, -5 etc. Now that I am ready to add these new objects to the database I want to clear their index value so that I can run a createService on them.

It wont allow me to delete object.property and setting it to 0 or trying to set it to null will not allow the object to be created in the database.

What other method can I use for clearing the property?

Comment: Can you please post some code so we can fully understand the context of your question?

Comment: indCSF.indcsf_id = 0; // Needs to be cleared!   createIndcsfResult.token = indcsfService.createIndcsf(indCSF);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Problem statement is not good enough.Still let me try to answer it(as per my understanding). I suspect you are trying to add it to database table where index property is set to autoIncrement. If it is so, why do you need to set index such as -1,-2,-3 etc. Simply maintain a collection of your objects without giving them any index. Anyway, new Item will only be added at the end of the collection, so you can be sure about the index sequencing.

Comment: I have an arrayCollection of of indCSF that are input from an array of one line components that can be added to or taken away from each of their pages using as [-] or [+] button next to them. Those rows that have content in I copy there index to the row so I know which row needs updating in the array and then the database. Binding is not possible with the complexity of the interface. When new rows are created I need to refrence them to the array index and I need to maintain their position within the form so I used the row number but as negative instead of positive to indicate that it....

Comment: ... will need creating rather than updating. Thus now I have the array Object as negative I'd like to remove the negative and create the row. I tried adding a new valueObject but it just created 2 rows in the database the one I added and the original one. When I just try to create the original one with an index of 0 it just dosn't create.